# регулярное выражение C++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день,

Имеется Visual Studio .sln, в нём описаны проекты которые в данном солюшене. Так мне необходимо выбрать названия проектов в этом файле. [Вот пример](http://pastebin.com/11VafVPj) как выглядит внутри солюшн. Обработку строки и тд реализовал, но вот определить точно подходит ли мне текущая строка не могу. Узнал что для этого можно использовать `regex_search()` и регулярные выражения. Только [вот мой](http://pastebin.com/2N0D37ba) составленный шаблон не работает.

Само регулярное выражение долно быть типа :

> слово("{цифры буквы и знак - }") = "цифры-буквы", "цифры-буквы знаки \ . и всегда окончание .vcxproj", "{цифры-буквы}"

Или вот сам пример из .sln

> Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "ConsoleApplication1", "ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj", "{3136B732-9CB7-4B25-8CEA-3DCCD0634A6C}"

Comment: Может вам выбрать более простой способ разпарсить файл? Разбить данные по запятым, с игнорированием запятой в "" и отсеять текст в кавычках? Тем более раз вы уже парсите файл такой сложности то массив char проще просканировать прогнав for()

Comment: А такой подойдет: `boost::regex projParse("Project\\(\"\\{[\\w-]+\\}\"\\)\\s*=\\s*\"(\\w+)\"[,\\s]+\"([^\"]+\\.vcxproj)\"[,\\s]+\"(\\{[\\w-]+\\})\"")`?

Comment: Я запилил бы какую функцию сюда сам, но мой руководитель проекта требует, чтобы в случае видоизменения (из-за версии) кода .sln, с лёгкостью можно было бы изменить шаблон и всё.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, выглядит красиво, сейчас потестю, проверю.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, вы видимо где-то знак " пропустили или один лишний

Comment: Более непригодной к изменениям вещи, чем *достаточно сложное* регулярное выражение трудно придумать.

Comment: В общем, [смотрите тут](https://regex101.com/r/sV7vS3/1).

Comment: А почему Вы [испортили строковый литерал](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595356/incorrect-regular-expression-in-c)? Могли бы и тут обновить вопрос, или комментарий написать. Т.е. всё-таки нужен не Boost?

Comment: Регулярные выражения (boost::regex) работают очень медленно и нужны для действительно сложных случаев. В Вашем достаточно загрузить в память файл, а потом линейно пройти по нему, по пути собирая заранее собранные паттерны, и извлекая нужную инфу.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew boost используется в проекте сам по себе, я создал отдельный проект, чтобы протестить эту фичу